# How to iterate over a string to create a new string?

Tags: javascript, string

I just want to iterate over "banana" and exchange each letter with "A" to obtain a new string "AAAAAA". Why this code doesn't work?

```
let word = "banana";
for (letter of word)
 {
  letter = "A";
  return word;
 }
```

Comment: The `letter`  variable is not a reference (pointer) to the character of the string. Strings are immutable. You actually need to create a *new* string.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually overwritting the [local variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Local_variable) `letter` once, then you return the unchanged `word`

If you want to replace all letters by a `'A'`, you can [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) that letter as much time as the length of the string :

```js
let word = 'banana';

word = 'A'.repeat(word.length);

console.log(word);
```

Comment: Thank you. But can we do this task using for of loop?

Comment: Yes, by creating a **new string** and looping `word.length` times. You can't change the original string in place, since strings are immutables

Answer (score 1):

Your code isnt working for several reasons: the letter variable you get in the for of loop is only suppose to be a reference you shouldnt change it, also the return statement you setup does nothing you cant return from a for loop. I would do it this way:

```
let word = "banana"
//We repeat the string "A" by the length of the string
const convertedString = 'A'.repeat(word.length)
console.log(convertedString)
```

(Edit) Using for of loop:

```
  let word = "banana";
  let convertedString = "";

  //we set the paramater as _ because we dont need it of course you can change it back to letter
  for (_ of word) {
    //when using the += it means that we do this: convertedString = convertedString + "A"
    convertedString += "A";
  }

  console.log(convertedString);
```

Comment: Thank you. But can we do this task using for of loop?

Comment: I tried this code in Chrome console and it returns NaN:

let word = "banana";
let word2 = "";

for (letter of word)
{
 word2 =+ "A";
}

Comment: Be careful =+ is not the same as +=

Comment: Oh yes now it works, big thanks, I'm a total newbie:-) I appreciate your help.

Comment: BTW You can set a answer as a actuall answer by clicking the green mark to the left of it :>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace each character, you can use .replace() with a regex for exchange each letter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Regular_expression.

```
let word = "banana";
let regex = /([A-z])/g //
let pSplit = word.replace(regex,"A");
console.log(pSplit);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tw85bnp4/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```js
let word = "banana";
let letters = "";
for (i of word){
    letters += "A"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a return statement in the for loop, will return directly after the first iteration, and will return the value of variable word which is `banana`

You could also replace every non whitespace `\S` char with A

```js
let word = "banana";
console.log(word.replace(/\S/g, 'A'));
```

Other options could be using split and map:

```js
let word = "banana";
console.log(word.split('').map(_ => 'A').join(''));
```

Or for example a plain for loop:

```js
let word = "banana";
let letters = '';
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  letters += 'A';
}
console.log(letters);
```